# Emacs crash because of special utf-8 character

Tags: utf-8, crash

I am trying to open a file that contains the following utf-8 character: ⛺
Unfortunately, my emacs does really not appreciate, and immediately crashes.
I have tried to comment out all my `init.el` (and actually I've even renamed my `.emacs_d` folder to be sure that my local packages/functions have nothing to do with it).
The crash still occurs (it just closes the editor when attempting to open the file).

Any idea of what the problem might be/how to fix this ?
Using emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit: here is the terminal output when running `emacs -Q --debug-init`.
No message on startup.
When trying to paste ⛺ in the scratch buffer:

```
X protocol error: BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error) on protocol request 139
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
Fatal error 6: Aborted
...  // long backtrace ending with a core dump
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you can start emacs without init file by invoking the command `emacs -Q`. Adding `--debug-init` starts emacs in debug mode

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the debug mode (and about the -Q). I'll add the error message to my message.

Comment: This is the infamous Xft + emoji bug. Either upgrade to emacs-27, or to an emacs-26 build compiled with Cairo support.

Comment: I get the same behavior (i.e. emacs crashes) when inserting certain unicode characters. In my case, some of the command line tools that I'm using output empty circles (○) and filled circles (⏺) for checked and unchecked options, respectively.  I did manage to crash Emacs for other types of circles, while using `counsel-unicode-char`. I'm using emacs 26.1 on Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the same crash. Quoting the likely-looking answer from @rpluim:

> This is the infamous Xft + emoji bug. Either upgrade to emacs-27, or to an emacs-26 build compiled with Cairo support. – rpluim

As discussed at [#30045 - Emoji causing Emacs (GTK+3 backend) to crash - GNU bug report logs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30045)
and
[Modifying Frontsets](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifying-Fontsets.html),
a quick workaround is to disable the problematic font for colored emoji via M-:

> (add-to-list 'face-ignored-fonts "Noto Color Emoji")